# Windows 10 Docker with VBox paradox. Virtual Box wouldn't run unless Hyper-V is disabled and Docker wouldn't start unless Hyper-V is enabled

Tags: docker, virtualbox, hyper-v

When I have Hyper-V enabled, and I try to run my Ubuntu 19.04 VM, I get the following error:

```
(VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API).
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

However, when I disable Hyper-V and try to run Docker Desktop, I get the error that Docker cannot start unless Hyper-V is enabled.

Comment: Why do you need to use VM and docker in paraller on same host machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Docker Toolbox, the version that can work without Hyper-V.

https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/